# why is `read_excel()` from package `readxl` reading zeros?

Tags: r, excel, xls, readxl

I'm trying to read this excel file (xls) into a tibble.
[image]

But when I read it with the `read_excel` function this happens (the three first columns are filled with zeros, even the col names).`

`read_excel(archivo_estm, sheet = "Humedad", col_types = "text")`

[image]

I've already tried using the `xlsx` package but when I used Rstudio crash.

Comment: Please at least show the code you used to read in the file.

Comment: My best guess would be it has something to do with merged cells in the header. Maybe try skipping the first 4 rows.

Comment: I tried that but it remains the same.

Comment: Can you give a column name in column A, say (`N`)?

Comment: yes, it can with `rename`